# Input validation cannot exceed initial value jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two input fields that need validation but I'm having trouble with storing the initial value of one of the fields.

The first field for example has value 10, so the input cannot be greater than 10.

My thought was to get the value onfocus and store it in a global var, but the variable keeps changing.

The two functions for validation are just to check if the ammount are valid

```
var original_amount;
var original_purchprice;

    $('#order').on({
        focus: function() {
            original_amount = $('.order_amount').val();
            original_purchprice = $('.order_purchprice').val();
        },
        keyup: function() {
            var amount = $('.order_amount').val();
            var purchprice = $('.order_purchprice').val();
            var isValid_amount = true;
            var isValid_purchprice = true;

            if(!isValidAmmount(amount) || (amount > original_amount)){
                 isValid_amount = false;
            }

            if(!roundPositiveNumber(purchprice)){
                isValid_purchprice = false;
            } 

            if(isValid_amount == true && isValid_purchprice == true) {
                $('#save_order').prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                $('#save_order').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }
    }, '.order_amount, .order_purchprice');
```

HTML

```
<input type='text' class='order_amount' value=10>
<input type='text' class='order_purchprice'value=69.95>
```

Comment: Provide your html code for more understanding

Comment: It's just two input fields nothing more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store original values of every input using jQuery `data` method (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).

Then listen to `keyup` event and compare the current value of the input with the initial value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.order_amount').each(function(){
        $(this).data('original_amount', $(this).val());
    });

    $('.order_purchprice').each(function(){
        $(this).data('original_purchprice', $(this).val());
    });

    $('#order').on({
        keyup: function() {

           var $current_input = $(this);
           var current_amount = $current_input.val();
           var original_amount = $current_input.data('original_amount');

           // other logic goes here
       }
    }, '.order_amount, .order_purchprice');

});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/c07mc2L1/13/.

Comment: Yeah maybe I should've mentoined it, but there multiple input field of the same, for instance an order could have 10 parts so than I have 10x amount and purchprice

Comment: I've updated my answer. When updating the amount, do you need to compare the purchprice also? Give me your feedback so I can finish it.

Comment: thanks! The purchprice doesn't need to be compared only the amount